# Waiting on isDisplyable for a component

Tags: java, swing, invokelater

testing a game, i sometimes get exceptions thrown when a component is not displayable. i added a wait loop on isDisplayable().

seems like my game can take a few hundred ms. to become displayable.

is this a sane way to handle this problem?

i am testing game clients that talk over sockets to a server.

thanks

edit 1: thanks for the comments. i discovered that i am adding the mediator for the gui (an observer) to the model (an observable) before the gui completes its construction and initialization. it gets worse, as i am initializing a panel with calls to createImage which returns null and throws.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class WaitForFrameToBeVisible {
    JFrame frame=new JFrame("FrameDemo");
    private void createAndShowGUI() {
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JLabel emptyLabel=new JLabel("");
        emptyLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(175,100));
        frame.getContentPane().add(emptyLabel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    void run() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("waiting for frame to be displayable");
        long t0=System.nanoTime();
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
        while (!frame.isDisplayable())
            Thread.sleep(1);
        long dt=System.nanoTime()-t0;
        System.out.println("waited "+dt/1_000_000.+" ms. for frame to be displayable");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new WaitForFrameToBeVisible().run();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would "guess" you have a thread race condition between the time it takes the Swing API to construct and validate the UI and what ever is trying to update it, but it's hard to tell.  No, personally, it's not a sane way to approach the problem, Swing is not thread safe so you're risking a different race condition.  What I might consider trying is using a `WindowListener` and listening for a change in visibility, but you'd have to test it further to 100% sure

Comment: Why are you doing Swing stuff in a thread that isn't the Swing/AWT thread?

Comment: @immibis which stuff are you talking about?

Comment: @MapProgrammer i have a hierarchy changed listener. perhaps it's better to wait on that? i am testing game clients that talk over sockets to a server.

Comment: @RayTayek Not really, the `hierarchy` could be modified before the components are made "displayable" (via `pack` and `setVisible` of the frame).  It's actually very hard to guarantee that a component is displayable, as so much depends on the underlying OS implementation.  Normally, I use a `WindowListener` and when the window is made visible, use a `invokeLater` just to be "more" sure that I can make the changes I need to the components.  Remember, Swing is NOT thread safe, you should never try to change or check the state of the components out side of the context of the EDT

Comment: @RayTayek Without a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem, it's very difficult to make suggestions about how you might fix the problem.  For example, you might use a producer/consumer or maybe an observer pattern instead

Comment: I think RayTayek don't want to make any changes in the frame which he is testing. And want any solution which could be done from outside. @MadProgrammer

Comment: @afzalex BUT, the Swing API is NOT thread safe.  You can't query the state of the UI from outside the context of the EDT with any certainty, you risk a thread race condition

Comment: @RayTayek Well `isDisplayable` for one.

Comment: !isDisplayable() == exception from RepaintManager that kills current JVM instance (can be closed by using system TaskManager)

Comment: Thread.sleep(1); is under latency for CPU/GPU, standard is about =>16

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `isDisplayable()`. You could use `invokeAndWait(...)` for what you are trying to do :

```
 javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
         createAndShowGUI();
     }
 });
 // control will reach here when the GUI will be created
```

*Notice that this way you are not actually checking if the frame is visible but you are checking if createAndShowGUI() has done its work*

Another thing is you should not call `isDisplayable()` or any function like this in loop. It will consume unnecessary processing speed. Instead use wait-notify.

But as far as your case is concerned to use `WindowListener` is very good idea as suggested by [MadProgrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/992484/madprogrammer) in comment.

Comment: Waiting for `invokeAndWait` to return won't guarantee that the frame is visible or displayable as the process can generate other events which get added to the EDT after the `createAndShowGUI` has finished (and the `invokeAndWait` has returned) - It's just another race condition

Comment: I think I explained it just after writing the code.

Comment: But, you shouldn't have even bothered mentioning it, it doesn't really solve the problem and introduces yet another possible race condition.  Just like you should never modify a component out side of the context of the EDT, you should never query the state of them either, as it's just tempting a race condition :P